# What the converse of a Statement .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

There is a statement $S$: "if a is not $a$ rational number, then $\sqrt[6]{a}$ is also not a rational number".

I don't know if the converse of statement S will be "if a is a rational number, then $\sqrt[6]{a}$ is also a rational number"

$or$

"if $\sqrt[6]{a}$ is not a rational number, then $a$ is also not a rational number"

Comment: The converse of $p \rightarrow q$ is $q \rightarrow p$. Your first statement is the inverse, second one is the converse

Comment: Thanks a lot，I understand now @lgor